# Why Kendo dataSouce.transport.update method do not send data to the server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I have a Kendo UI TreeList where every row has a checkbox displayed. If the user clicks on the checkbox then a request goes to the server and save the data. Unfortunately, I did something wrong because:

- the update method does not send data to the server
- and the sync method is not called automatically

What I did wrong?

I think the problem around how I set up that which item has changed. As you can see I iterate over the dataset coming from [dataSource.data()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data) and the item.checked and item.dirty properties are updated. If I understand correctly the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-autoSync) then this changes should trigger the sync method. It does not trigger the sync method and this it the reason I call it in the method.

My other question is related to the data structure should be sent to the server. It is based on the schema, right? So, once I can achieve that the request sends an object to the server I should create a similar C# POCO as model and I can read the data in the webapi controller.

In the documentation there is a [saveRow()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist#methods-saveRow) method, but I cannot translate that code to angular. Can somebody help me in this case?

```js
//this row is my problem
var treeList = $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList");
```

```js
var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: configurationService.goNoGoWebApiRootUrl + 'AreaPathDependencies/Get/ChildrenMarked/' + selectedAreaPathIdFromModalService,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "get"
                    },
                    update:
                        {
                            url: configurationService.goNoGoWebApiRootUrl + 'AreaPathDependencies/Update/AreaPathDependencies',
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "post"
                        },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        parentId: "parentId",
                        fields: {
                            Id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            ParentId: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Name: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Checked: { type: "boolean", editable: true, nullable: false }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            vm.treeListOptions = {
                dataSource: dataSource,
                sortable: false,
                editable: false,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "checked",
                        title: "Selected",
                        template: checkBoxTemplate,
                        width: 32
                    },
                    { field: "name", title: "Area Path", width: "200px", expandable: true },
                    { field: "fullPath", title: "FullPath", width: "500px" },
                ],
                save: onSave,
                change: onChange,
                sync: sync,
                autoSync: true,
            };

        }

        function checkboxOnclick(selectedId) {
            console.log('checkboxOnclick', selectedId);
            var data = vm.treeListOptions.dataSource.data();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                if (selectedId == data[i].id) {
                    data[i].set("checked", true);
                    //data[i].dirty = true;
                }
            }

            vm.treeListOptions.dataSource.sync();

            //console.log('flush', vm.treeListOptions.dataSource.data());
        }
```

Comment: Please, try set batch: true ([batch docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-batch)) into your dataSource (on the same level as transport and schema).

Comment: Wow! It works! However, I need to call the sync method. The question still stands whether I need to call the sync method or the change in the datamodel should be persisted by widget automatically. Why the bacth:true is needed? It is a defect? Please write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well *batch: true* has to be set to get *parameterMap* working, because models parameters will be available only when the batch option is enabled. ([parameterMap docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap))

And to second question - I am not so sure but as noted in [sync](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sync) docs,

> The sync method will request the remote service if:
>
> - the transport.create option is set and the data source contains new data items
> - the transport.destroy option is set and data items have been removed from the data source
> - the transport.update option is set and the data source contains updated data items

How I understand to that - to get *sync* method working you need to return updated records. Please check, if your server method for update/delete returns that.